# Phonon doesn't work in QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, audio, video, qgraphicsscene, phonon

The following code

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Phonon::MediaObject *media = new Phonon::MediaObject();
Phonon::VideoWidget *video = new Phonon::VideoWidget(NULL);
video->setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200);
Phonon::createPath(media, video);
Phonon::MediaSource source("1.avi");
media->setCurrentSource(source);
media->play();
video->show();
return a.exec();
```

shows me a video. its ok.
But this:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QGraphicsScene scene;
Phonon::MediaObject *media = new Phonon::MediaObject();
Phonon::VideoWidget *video = new Phonon::VideoWidget(NULL);
video->setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200);
Phonon::createPath(media, video);
Phonon::MediaSource source("1.avi");
media->setCurrentSource(source);
media->play();
QGraphicsProxyWidget * pWidget = scene.addWidget(video,Qt::Widget);
QGraphicsView view(&scene);
view.show();
return a.exec();
```

shows me a widget with a white background.. but where is my video ? ;) If i connect audiooutput to media, i hear sound of movie, so stream is going on.
where is the mistake ? (Qt 4.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Displaying `QWidget` in `QGraphicsScene` is quite tricky. See [QGraphicsProxyWidget](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qgraphicsproxywidget.html#details) description for more information. Basically, the widget you see in `QGraphicsView` is not *real* widget. `QGraphicsView` just redirects paint events to the underlying invisible `QWidget`. It seems that video redirection is not supported here.

I think you should not put your widget inside scene. Consider placing it above the graphics view, for example.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there way to determinate that paint redirect is not supported ?
And, if i can't do that on my platform, does it means that i can't over draw my video ? ;( I need draw playback buttons at the bottom of the video in full screen mode. I didnt find another way to do that, except using QGraphicsScene.

Comment: Try to add a child widget (button) to your video widget without layout and set its position with `move()`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17341131/344347).

Comment: I tried your variant, but got something like this: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3K5B_5jQrkRYXBmSEk5S1VnNk0/edit?usp=sharing. Video starts from the offset 0 again, where i put a button.